# How to inject a implementation that takes some value in its constructor in Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have following implementation that I am trying to Inject in Guice

```
`public class Client{ 
   private final Database db; 
   public Client(Database db){ 
     this.db = db 
   } 
}

class SomeClass{ 
  private Client client; 

  @Inject 
  public SomeClass(Client client){ 
    this.client = client; 
  } 
}`
```

This is my injection code
Injector guice = Guice.Injector();
guice.getInstance(SomeClass.class);

But I keep on getting the error:

> Could not find a suitable constructor in
>   hello.package.helloworld.Client. Classes must have either one (and
>   only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument
>   constructor that is not private

How do I Inject a class that already takes some parameter?

Comment: Please share your injector class..

Comment: Kindly consider this [link](http://blog.muhuk.com/2015/05/28/using_guice_effectively.html#.WZZGs1UjHIU) where you would resolve your issue. For more help consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105895/constructor-injection-using-guice and from this [link](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaDependencyInjection) consider configurable bindings.

Answer (score 0):

The error text is quite explicit: you haven't used `@Inject` on the constructor of `Client`.

So the idea is to make it so:

```
public class Client{ 
  private final Database db; 
  @Inject
  public Client(Database db){ 
    this.db = db 
  } 
}
```

And if you don't know your database, but want to create it, consider using Guice's [assisted injection](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject), that creates factory for you.